# What does this stand for in oracle regex ?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What will the following statement do in oracle regex ?

`REGEXP_REPLACE(X,'[[:digit:].]','')`

Comment: well, what do you think "digit" matches? Ponies? I have never used Oracle but it's entirely obvious to me what this is supposed to do. Even without reading the documentation. But you could have easily done that as well.

Comment: What happened when you tried yourself?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant but what about . followed by [:digit:] mean ?

Comment: @Aneesh again, docs. As explained by the answer below, it's a literal dot.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be escaped ? Doesn't it mean any character ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all digits and dots from X

**[:digit:]** is a special Oracle function (POSIX character classes). Other examples:

**[:alnum:]** Alphanumeric characters. Includes letters and numbers. Omits
punctuation marks.
**[:alpha:]** Alphabetic characters. Includes letters only.
**[:blank:]** Blank space characters.
**[:cntrl:]** Control (non-printing) characters.
**[:digit:]** Numeric characters.
**[:graph:]** All [:punct:], [:upper:], [:lower:], [:digit:] character classes
combined.
**[:lower:]** Lowercase alphabetic characters.
**[:print:]** Printable characters.
**[:punct:]** Punctuation characters.
**[:space:]** Space (non-printing) characters.
**[:upper:]** Uppercase alphabetic characters.
**[:xdigit:]** Valid hexadecimal characters.

And "." (dot) inside [] means "dot"

Answer (score 1):

this function will replace all the characters in X witch is not a number with empty string 
in other terms it s gonna send back a number filter
let s say

```
X=asd123sqsd2345
REGEXP_REPLACE(X,'[[:digit:].]','')
x=>1232345
```